# ffmpeg compilation error message on windows 7

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

- I have downloaded source for ffmpeg, libfdk_aac
- I installed MinGW/MinSys shell
- I compiled libfdk_aac without any issues.

But when I try to compile ffmpeg, I get an error. Do I need to download source code for yasm and libx264 as well to build ffmpeg for H264 and libfdk_aac?

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/mingw/i686-w64-mingw32 --enable-libx264 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-w32threads --enable-memalign-hack --enable-shared
```

Error Message I am getting:

```
yasm not found, use --disable-yasm for a crippled build

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do need yasm to build x264.

Unfortunately I cannot guide with respect to building on windows- but it cannot be too different from linux. Only thing is I don't know how the x264 or other such as libfdk_aac get connected. In linux they are built separately and installed separately, but saying --enable-libx264 in the ./configure is good enough to connect the two by providing the support inside ffmpeg.